# Show UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uinavigationbar

Here's the deal... I can't get the UINavigation bar to appear on one of my views. I have the whole thing in a NavigationViewController in IB and turned of the navigation bar though IB because I don't want it in most of my app but when I try to show the navigation bar via code, it doesn't show up.

here's the code I used to try to get the nav bar to show up... but didn't work:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

respectfully,
Matt

Comment: Definitely agree with the above comment. Out of everything you can post, the most obvious thing to post would be to post the "when I try to show the navigation bar via code" code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you write should only work inside of one of UINavigationController's **controllers**, not views.

So, if you call it from your view, you should replace **self** with controller name,in which this view is placed.

Comment: the problem was that I set up transitions in the modal method. This disrupted the nav controller